# Whats the best way for continous integration for Javafx-Rich-Client-Applications

Tags: tomcat, build, continuous-integration, hudson, javafx

hmm... i wonder

So, lets say we have an Appache Tomcat 7 and a Hudson Server is already up and Running. The Hudson Server is already building and deploying the Middleware and Share projects (wich are pure maven projects) of the target application.
Now the only thing i want is to let Hudson deploy the already build (by Netbeans) JavaFX rich client or even better (and of course harder) build, compress, package, sign and deploy the rich client to the server.

I have seen some beta maven plugins that promise to do all this magic stuff but never managed to get them up an running.

So any thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ant script according to the [JavaFX deployment guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm).  This will accomplish the build, compress, package, sign steps.

I believe NetBeans operates on an ant build script which makes use of the JavaFX ant tasks - so you may be able to use the NetBeans UI to set up the build script for your app and still execute the resultant script from Hudson rather than inside NetBeans.

The JavaFX ant script can be triggered from Hudson - here is a [step by step description of the setup and process](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_98/jdtut_11r2_98_3.html).

Use a [Hudson scp plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/SCP+plugin) to perform the deployment to a server.

If you prefer to use Maven to define your builds, then you can try the [zenjava maven plugin for JavaFX](http://www.zenjava.com/2012/11/24/from-zero-to-javafx-in-5-minutes/).  (I have not used that plugin, so cannot vouch for it's suitability).  Should you go that route, there is extensive documentation on the Hudson site on integrating Hudson and Maven.

I'd prefer [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) over Hudson, but it probably makes little difference which you use.